# nginx - no ssl for crawlers / bots

Tags: ssl, nginx

In a server directive for port 80 in nginx I want to redirect all requests to https **if** the user agent is not a bot. I tried using this:

```
...
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent !~* (bot|spider|crawler|sniffer|facebook) ) {
        return 301 https://host.com$request_uri;
    }

    include other-stuff.inc;
}
```

I thought nginx would stop on the `return` but it doesn't. It still processes the `include` (which serves the normal site) and does not redirect. (If I comment the `include` it does the redirect, though).

Comment: The include is executed when parsing the config at startup. But the `if` is executed for the requests.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Then still the question is how can I stop the request with the return 301?

Comment: Can you post the contents of other-stuff.inc?

Comment: Usually this is the right way to do, but maybe something you've done in the include file changes the behavior. Check log files, maybe some error cause that this section does not get processed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add a break after the return it would work, try this

```
if (whatever){
  return 301 ...;
  break;
}
# include and the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your includes you have some other locations?
If so, you may have an issue with 'if' working differently depending on a context. This is explained [here](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html)

You may try to move it to server configuration:

```
server {

... server config

    if ($http_user_agent !~* (bot|spider|crawler|sniffer|facebook) ) {
        return 301 https://host.com$request_uri;
    }
    location / {

        include other-stuff.inc;
    }
}
```